# Create Installer for Application that passes parameters to application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, installation, dependencies

So I have an application that has dependencies, web drivers for Selenium. I want to include the drivers in my program, or optionally just ask the user what browser they would like to use this application with, and include the proper driver. But during install, I would like to save the file path of the driver to load the selenium web driver. I thought about creating a .txt file when the user specifies their path into that folder, and using that. But all the "create an application installer" guides I've come across just use another app to create their installer. There is really no installation, there is just a light weight .exe main program, and then the web drivers. But I need to configure the web driver in the program.